# problem with mapping a many-to-many relation (mapping by code)

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using a new to NHibernate 3.2 mapping by code (not fluent nhibernate) and I have a little problem with mapping a many-to-many relation.

I want to map these entities

```
 public class Article
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { set; get; }
        public virtual string Content { set; get; }
        public virtual string Title { set; get; }
        public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { set; get; }
    }
 public class Tag
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { set; get; }
        public virtual string Name { set; get; }
        public virtual IList<Article> Articles { set; get; }
    }

    public class ArticleTag
    {
        public virtual Article Article { set; get; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { set; get; }
    }
```

My mapping looks that

```
  public class TagMapping : ClassMapping<Tag>
        {
            public TagMapping()
            {
                Id<Guid>(x => x.Id);
                Property<string>(x => x.Name);
                Bag<Article>(x => x.Articles, x => x.Inverse(true), x => x.ManyToMany(z =>
                {
                    z.Column("Article");
                    z.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
                }));
            }
        }
        public class ArticleTagMapping : ClassMapping<ArticleTag>
        {
            public ArticleTagMapping()
            {
                ManyToOne<Article>(x => x.Article, x => { });
                ManyToOne<Tag>(x => x.Tag, x => { });
            }
        }
       public class ArticleMapping : ClassMapping<Article>
        {
            public ArticleMapping()
            {
                Id<Guid>(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Guid));
                Property<string>(x => x.Content, x => x.Length(4002));
                Property<string>(x => x.Title);
                Bag<Tag>(x => x.Tags, x =>{ }, x => x.ManyToMany(z =>
                {
                    z.Column("Tag");
                    z.Lazy(LazyRelation.Proxy);
                }));
            }
        }
```

The only problem is that, when I generate tables in database using this schema, I have two additional tables. What I must change to disable generating these two tables (Articles and Tags)?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need this?:

```
 public class ArticleTagMapping : ClassMapping<ArticleTag>
        {
            public ArticleTagMapping()
            {
                ManyToOne<Article>(x => x.Article, x => { });
                ManyToOne<Tag>(x => x.Tag, x => { });
            }
        }
```

Comment: I already figured it out, if I remove this mapping, the database tables diagram will look like I want to. But I don't want to have a relation in code 1:1. I want in code have the same situation, that means n:m relation divided to three entities. I don't want a situation, that I have e.g. customer:company relation and now I need to add a DateTime object to check when customer was associated with company. I have problem, how to appropriate mapping this relation.

Comment: For what I can see, that is not a N:M (well it is DB level), but I guess what you are seeing at the end are two relationships of 1:N type. customer (1) - (N) company_customer (N) - (1) company. What you think?

Comment: "...run into a situation where you have what appears to be a many-to-many relationship, but the “join table” has extra, non-ID data columns in it. This is not a real many-to-many relationship. It is, in fact, a ternary relationship. Another way of looking at it is two OTM/MTO relationships between the two main tables and the intermediate table (i.e., the “join table” with extra information). You can think of it logically as a many-to-many relationship, but you should model it as a ternary relationship." taken from http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0907121&printmode=true